# Please change my regex patterns

Tags: regex

my text is :

```
<Parag 1 Lev="All">
text All
</Parag1>
<Parag 2 Lev="That">
text That
</Parag2>
<Parag 3 Lev="Com">
text Com in tag 3
</Parag3>
<Parag 4 Lev="All">
text All
</Parag4>
<Parag 5 Lev="All">
text All
</Parag5>
<Parag 6 Lev="Com">
text Com in tag 6
</Parag6>
<Parag 7 Lev="That">
text That
</Parag7>
```

1- How can I get text between tags with Lev="Com" with regular expression ? for example : `text Com in tag 3` or `text Com in tag 6`

Please change my Expr : `("Com">)[\d\D]+(</)`

2- How can I get tags with regular expression ? for example : `<Parag 1 Lev="All">` or `</Parag1>` or `<Parag 3 Lev="Com">` or `</Parag3>`

Please change(or merge) my Exprs : `(<Parag.*?>)(</Parag.*?>)`

Thank's.

Comment: Please change the title of your question.

Comment: Is your XML meant to be malformed, or is it typo? e.g. should Parag 7 Lev"That" be <Parag7 Lev="That"> ?

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to use a regex to recognize/modify XML.  Simply because regular expressions are...well...regular.  They're less expressive than context free languages like XML.  So, as soon as you nested XML elements, your regex becomes useless.  You CAN use regex for simple cases, but you're better off using XSL from the start.

Comment: Thank's Jakrabbit from your suggestion, but I don't use xml for my text. Because my text is a persian text that not have special grammer similar xml grammer(syntax). My question is samples for receive syntax or grammer for writing text. please help me for merge regex patterns of question two. Thank's of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern could be:

```
"Com">([^<]+)</
```

The text will be in group 1. Depending on your pattern tool you may need to allow pattern matching over endlines:

```
Pattern.compile("your pattern",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Second question:

```
<Parag([^>]+)>|</Parag([^>]+)>
```

Comment: Thank's. please help me for second question.

Comment: For second question, please get me one pattern that include 2 state(<Parag 1 Lev"All"> and </Parag1>)